# Can I add "virtual" page in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

On my WordPress site, I would like to create "virtual" page. By virtual page I mean the content that I can link to by URL. I'm using Facebook Webhooks and I would like to have a callback URL like this: `https://example.com/facebook-webhook`. I'd like it to be done via plugin, without actually adding any page to the database. Is there any way to add a page in WordPress that way?

For now I'm using `https://example.com/?facebook-webhook` and checking for `isset( $_GET['facebook-webhook'] )` in the `init` action. I would love to have it without the `?` though.

Comment: Have you tried adding a new `.htaccess` rule?

Comment: @NazmulAlamNayan I want it to be done in plugin-like way, so I need to be able to disable it without touching any code.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you have enabled the link customization, all the incoming url are processed by wordpress, and you can pre-process it. Year ago I have made a similar plugin. I have to go, now, but if you are interested I can search-it. BRB

Comment: @fusion3k Sure, any help is appreciated. However, I need a solution that will work for any config.

Comment: I guess [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) will help you. It will let you add a custom rewrite rule without touching any code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a rewrite and query vars to use your custom php file as a template:

```
//1. define a path for later
define('PLUG_PATH', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)));



//2. add a wp query variable to redirect to
add_action('query_vars','plugin_set_query_var');
function plugin_set_query_var($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'is_new_page'); // ref url redirected to in add rewrite rule

    return $vars;
}


//3. Create a redirect
add_action('init', 'plugin_add_rewrite_rule');
function plugin_add_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^mynewpage$','index.php?is_new_page=1','top');

    //flush the rewrite rules, should be in a plugin activation hook, i.e only run once...

    flush_rewrite_rules();  
}

//4.return the file we want...
add_filter('template_include', 'plugin_include_template');
function plugin_include_template($template){


    // see above 2 functions..
    if(get_query_var('is_new_page')){
        //path to your template file
        $new_template = PLUG_PATH.'/template.php';
        if(file_exists($new_template)){
            $template = $new_template;
        } 
        // else needed? up to you maybe 404?
    }    

    return $template;    

}
```

Comment: Isn't calling `flush_rewrite_rules` for each request quite heavy?

Comment: Will this solution work regardless of permalink settings? Even if someone uses `Plain` setting?

Comment: yes its using a rewrite rule, so when someone uses the url `example.com/mynewpage` it will match and redirect to the url in the rewrite.

Comment: actually sorry by plain you mean default? no it wont, wp wont load rewrite for this....you would need to use a early hook and include the file and load wp if you want that, not a great way to do it!

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I think WP doesn't use .htaccess at all for `Plain` setting - am I right? Actually I need to use it as a callback only, so I need to just perform certain action and echo text. What I did now is checking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and performing the action if it's what I want it to be. That's quite low level solution, isn't it?

Comment: it does use htaccess -- thats apache -- it dosent run the rewrite process though, theres no need. What do you mean echo text? is it a endpoint for json/ ajax maybe?

Comment: No, it is a callback for Facebook webhook :)

Comment: ok cant really help you there, been too long since i worked with FB. Server should work fine, you'll need to exit after including your file to stop a 404 redirect.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter if it's FB or not here I believe. It's just third party calling my site with `/foo` endpoint.

Comment: @RoboRobok please note that you have no chance to catch an incoming url without .htaccess modification.

Comment: @fusion3k Yes, I understand it. It works for me though, even on `Plain`. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @RoboRobok  Maybe you (or someone) has modified .htaccess but not activate the customization of url in wordpress. Look at the content of .htaccess file.

Comment: The funny thing is that I don't see `.htaccess` at all! :) I have no freaking idea where is it, but my WordPress site works. I haven't touched `.htaccess` manually.

Comment: @fusion3k htaccess is an apache file, you can set the same configuration in apache and in fact any rules set in htaccess do not override the apache config. You will often find this is the case on shared hosting platforms. Anyway all uri's go to the wp concept of an index file (process) and are routed to the correct files from there

Comment: @David yes, I know. I have supposed that if the .htaccess is set to redirect to wordpress in the past someone have activated custom link of wordpress, but maybe not.