# run php application within wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, wordpress

So I own a computer repair store. We have a point of sale software that we really like. There is a "check repair status" folder you can install this app on another website, I love the way this works, but want to incorporate it (deps.php, index.php, headerstatus.php, footerstatus.php, common.php) all into one file so I can execute that php in the post section of a WordPress page remove the
`<? php {php _code here} ?>` tags and replace them with `[insert_php] {php code here} [/insert_php]` with the use of a wordpress plugin "insert php" only the code between those two tags will be executed inside that WordPress page (inphp) it has been posted on.

The problem is it cannot reach out to another file from there it all has to be contained. Since wordpress pages aren't physical locations rather information from a DB. It would be nice to run that php from the page so I could easily just create a couple small custom class sizes for boxes and divs then delete all previous custom classes and styles in the php and allow the default class/styles from our theme take their place and custom styles/classes (likely inline)by me for those that aren't defined by the default css of our theme.

So is there command we could use to tell the index where to reference those functions, parameters, or commands from within the same file, as opposed to referencing separate files?

```
require("deps.php"); require("headerstatus.php"); require("common.php");
require_once("footerstatus.php");
function showstatus() { require("deps.php"); require("headerstatus.php"); require("common.php");
```

So if it's not possible to remove require, or use the require or another command to point at a localized function, line, or path in its place. either a (note I said possible, this code doesn't need to be perfect it needs to run from a single script and work. I understand people hate to recommend non standard answers to programming.)

How much work would it be to rewrite each individual item needed from the common, deps and php files to reflect the type of data its looking for?
Or would it make more sense to rewrite the code in the index to work better with localized functions?

The problem is that I need this to work, and can find no examples online which is not usually a good sign. I'm open to any and all suggestions!
Just throwing out ideas here, also if you make a suggestion please give an example.

Comment: It should be as simple as placing all code in one file and remove all the `require()`s.

Comment: We have tried that, we get an error message, at this point it looks like all 3 files contain functions or parameters the other 2 need. 

Based on what I've been reading, which may very well be wrong(I am no expert). I've read a few things that claim The lines that are being called upon by other functions need to come first in the file? Could someone confirm or deny this?

Comment: its very difficult to see what you are thinking, but you can run php on certain pages, you create a page template. The problem you are going to have is this is a lot of work, alternatively you can just park all the files in a folder and allow access to this folder in your htaccess, then you have it working (see the index.php?)

Comment: What error message did you get? If you can get it working in one script outside of WordPress first, then you can try copying it into your WP plugin. It sounds like the WP plugin only supports php, so you'll have to remove any html and css that is not `echo`ed out of php

Comment: That's the route I've been trying to take. When I place the Deps.php File at the top, then the Common.php, Then the Index.php File.

I get a "Could not connect the DB" Error 

any other combination of those files in any order i just see random characters all over the place. Almost as if there is a tag broken.

Comment: The problem I see with this(assuming previous statement is correct order of functions and parameters matters) is that all 3 files require the other 2, so unless there is a way to reference a line instead of a document, or some similar function.

Comment: @Tristan I can use html and scrips in the page normally, and the php when executed from the plugin should be able to use html from the rest of the page. if not echo is a perfectly fine option, most of the html and style options in those php files are echoed.


@ David yes I can see that this is alot of work, and we do currently have it running in a sub folder. but our website looks really nice and this page looks like a dog shat all over my monitor, plus clients lose all navigation options. I just spent 4 months working on this site should be done in a couple weeks. just trying to fit this in.

Comment: @David Continued  
  
to see what I'm talking about:  
Here is a link to one of our pages that is Finished(not everyone is)
http://www.accuratepctech.com/remote  
  
Here is a link to our currently running repair status on the same server:
http://www.accuratepctech.com/repairstatus

Comment: not the prettiest.... my way of doing this would be to change the html of the repairstatus templates (just view source and grab the header/footer off a wp page and replace) and make css changes. Otherwise you will need to examine all the processes and make functions in your wp system. You could create a redirect to point into its own seperate folder (see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161848/can-i-add-virtual-page-in-wordpress/35162776#35162776) but then its going to be a case of checking all the code to fix the issues that crop up...

Comment: OH @David I think I read your first post wrong the first time, lets see if I am understanding you better now?

You are saying I can make a folder and provide lets say 777 Access to them. then I can place my index in my Wordpress post using the [insert php] plugin? 

Assuming that I can how do I reference the Files in the folders i place with a path as opposed to the just being in the same folder?

Comment: no you dont even need to insert php into the db, just follow the rewrite example to point at repair status index.php file in its own folder. Then you will have wp loaded and can actually just insert `get_header()` in the php file to output the header etc.

Comment: That last comment is a pretty good idea as well. I would still need to get our Header/Footer/Navigation onto it as well, but trying to figure out how that is referenced in the WP DB may be easier than editing all of this code?

Yea moving the head section of the WordPress document makes decent sense, assuming that the theme doesn't store all its CSS in the DB as well.

Comment: view-source:http://accuratepctech.com/remote/ you can see the css files there. I tell you what, ill write up an answer to demonstrate this for you, ill have space to explain properly

Comment: updated below, please upvote and accept the answer, it was way more than I intended to do for you :0

Comment: It wont allow me to upvote too green for that apprerently, but you have my sincerest thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to preserve the folder structure of the application you want to insert. This way paths should still work, they are relative to the file so should still work.

so 
1. create a new folder in your theme called "repairstatus"

2. upload all the files into that -- index.php etc
3. Place the following code in your themes functions.php (or create a child theme

   ```
   //1. add a wp query variable to redirect to
   add_action('query_vars','plugin_set_query_var');
   function plugin_set_query_var($vars) {
       array_push($vars, 'is_repair_page'); // ref url redirected to in add rewrite rule

       return $vars;
   }


   //2. Create a redirect
   add_action('init', 'plugin_add_rewrite_rule');
   function plugin_add_rewrite_rule(){
       add_rewrite_rule('^repairstatus$','index.php?is_repair_page=1','top');

       //flush the rewrite rules, should be in a plugin activation hook, i.e only run once...

       //flush_rewrite_rules();  
   }

   //3.return the file we want...
   add_filter('template_include', 'plugin_include_template');
   function plugin_include_template($template){


       // see above 2 functions..
       if(get_query_var('is_repair_page')){
           //path to your template file
           $new_template = get_stylesheet_directory().'/repairstatus/index.php';
           if(file_exists($new_template)){
               $template = $new_template;
           } 
           // else needed? up to you maybe 404?
       }    

       return $template;    

   }
   ```

Now navigate to settings on the admin dashboard and click on permalinks. Just hit the save button. test at this stage, http://accuratepctech.com/repairstatus/ should open index.php (it will look funny for the moment)..

now mod the index.php file...all we need to do is comment out the headerstatus and footerstatus requires, they will break the html output...

We can use `get_header()` to load the header of the wp site which will load css, navigation etc. and `get_footer()` for the footer element.

```
    if (array_key_exists('func',$_REQUEST)) {

    $func = $_REQUEST['func'];

    } else {

    $func = "";

    }





    //loads header and related 
    get_header();


    function repairlookup() {

    require("deps.php");

    //require("headerstatus.php"); -->not needed, its only html

    require("common.php");

    //etc////////////


    //find require("footerstatus.php") and remove

    }

    get_footer();
```

now you should have a wp looking page just the index.php code will be unstyled. You can add the css in by using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

(note this is html, close php tags to use it) but id recommend you open this file and copy into your style.css in your theme, you can then change the css to suit.

Note this will probably work as is, but there may be errors so check the operation throughly. I'm going to recommend you google wpdb and update to use WP database functions (you can create seperate tables if you want) otherwise you have 2 db connections on the go. This will not be good for the performance of the website, it will load ok with 1 user but 3/4 concurrent users will start to slow everything down...

Comment: Well it'll take a few to get this all in and going, but that does sound tremendously easier. I will let you know how this works out for me

Comment: As far as the functions.php is concerned I'm looking at it right now, trying to decide what portions of the file to place it in. I'm also reading through the comments/notes the theme author left in that file.  
  
  
These are foreign to me, are they things I need to do? I was assuming because you listed them as a comment, or are you telling me what the function is doing?   
  
    `//flush the rewrite rules, should be in a plugin activation hook, i.e only run once...`   
  
  
   `//flush_rewrite_rules();`

Comment: I'm assuming the path to my theme files?  
'//path to your template file'  
  
Should be, but that's the folder that the functions.php file is in too, so can the path not be relative?
`'/public_html/wp-content/themes/brooklyn'`  
`also templates located in '/public_html/wp-content/themes/brooklyn'`   

It would appear the main template is broken into several files. I do have a child theme for this page as well.

(I hate that I have to press shift edit to line down! i keep making new comments when I don't mean too)

Comment: that was a ton of help! I know I'm not even close to done yet, but you really did go above and beyond. Thank You so much for actually trying to help out, I'm so used to forum trolls and jerks I don't even know how to react to online kindness to strangers at that level.

Comment: So I have looked around and the theme I'm using is brooklyn.

In the Template Folder I have 3 Files:

Comment: that are listed at templates but I don't feel like these are the files you are wanting me to find the path for, I looked for some templates but wasn't exactly sure what you were referencing.

What template's path do I need to obtain?

Comment: It was working like this in just a sub folder before, but I can feel how close I am to getting it my themes styles. I'm so close, I've gotten several error messages thus far while attempting to get header and footer, I am assuming the rest is done correctly. I don't know if adding that to functions helped us any or not. I think that I may want to contact the theme makers to attempt to help with location of their templates, headers footers, etc....  they know their file structure and code. @David you are the man. When I get it all done I will most definitely get you the info to check it out!

Comment: the template path is index.php in this case. If the repairstatus folder is in the root of the theme, it should work as it is (get_stylesheet_dir returns the current dir of the theme). don't worry about flush rewrite, it should only be run once, hence why i said just save the permalinks instead. just to confirm the second snippet was the index.php but only a snippet of it. you just need to remove the original header/footer call and replace with get_header/footer. is your old htaccess redirect still in place? the path is saying the folder is in your server root? (it should be in your theme!)

Comment: in my theme huh? I didnt think of that yea i put it in my server root, when you said accuratepctech.com/repairstatus that's back in the server root, so the redirect makes sense now. yea i can throw one of those on.

I thought you were talking about the general-template.php which i learned is in the includes folder since i responded last.

I will give it s shot!

Comment: I did move it there so now its sitting in [my ip]/public_html/wp-content/themes/brooklyn/repairstatus  
  
But I get a file not found page, so I'm going to try a flush again, just in case, then I may do a quick google on the situation at hand. Your advice seems pretty good so far so if you have any advice on what steps i should take at this point let me know.

Comment: Okay so now interesting things are happening!  
It's popping up as a blog page with all of the stock demo images...
then below the footer is the repair status form, and it looks decent.
but trying to figure out where and how to disable the blog content portion of only this page may be interesting.
also when i click the button on the repair lookup, the first function attempts to go here...  
  
`http://accuratepctech.com/repairstatus/index.php?func=showstatus`  
`Oops! That page can’t be found.`
`It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the links below or a search?`

Comment: I got the repairstatus script above the footer, but it would appear that the blog post comes as part of the header.php from the parent folder.

It would also seem that it is attempting to run but when it refreshes for  `function showstatus( )` it the site cant find the content. Oddly enough the contact form in the footer is also showing a validation error, like it was run but with invalid data or empty fields, but i did not run it, wonder what the deal with that is? that only seems to happen when i attempt to `function repairlookup( )`

Comment: ok..what you will need to do is get all the forms working now, check all form actions and change to point at the same url (" "). Now you cannot have 2 forms on the same page unless you name them both, but i dont think having 2 forms here is appropriate, so you will need to find how to remove the footer form

Comment: `action="index.php?func=showstatus"` needs to become `action="?func=showstatus"`

Comment: I'm on it man, makes sense. I'll keep ya posted thanks for stickin' with me

Comment: So the form works entirely as far as I can see it would appear that it conflicts with the stock header and footer some. blog shows up from header, and the footer just starts in the middle of the form. I was digging around the header earlier, and started removing the items out of the header that I didn't need. Looks like I may have to dig alot farther in. I was hoping this was it `<?php ut_before_content_hook(); // action hook, see inc/ut-theme-hooks.php ?>` since by according to the Wordpress support page the default location for the blog stuff is in content.php

Comment: That didn't work, but it does look like I can either write a custom header, and footer copying only pieces of code I want, or the the index.php we are using can get a page id like `is-repair` it looks like the file `template-part-hero.php` defines which pages get the `('portfolio')` there are only a few types and all undefined pages get tagged `is_singular`

Comment: Thank You so much for helping me get the form functional!

Comment: you can actually create a custom header just call it `header-special.php` you can call it with `get_header('special')` all you really need are the functions that call the header section, there can be a lot in there doing other things that you don't need.  In the index.php there were a few calls to the old header, double check all these are removed. If you find this too difficult you can actually just pop the outputted html into your custom header (see the source link above?)

Comment: No it doesn't sound overly difficult, I did a find header feature in index.php with filezilla I thought I had them all commented out. You know what? I didn't do that in the other files. I bet Those calls are in deps, and common., but I will go back through index as well.

(I do not see a source link above)

Comment: I'm having a horrible time getting the theme builders support staff to respond to anything on their forums. Their header is very complex I am having difficulty tracking down the element that brings in the body. i have found a few calls to other files that seem like it, but can not find the calls to the file I found in view source that i want to remove. very frustrating.

Comment: i think ask a new q for this and ill have a look. if the code is long save header.php as a googledoc. act would you mind upvoting the answer above?

Comment: I'ive been trying, I don't have enough street cred for that yet it would appear. I will after I get 2 more rep.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231351/editing-this-wordpress-theme-header-for-use-in-a-custom-page

Yea I threw it up for ya. Honestly I got no reply from the theme developer, I'm kinda pissed about it. Also surprised I received no replies from anyone else here on stack, but the question is up.

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: it was a bit of a rant in the question and not really a minimal example or defined issue so it would have been hard for someone to answer the q! I have edited it a bit, but need the header.php file.

Comment: i put a copy of the entire theme including the repair status folder up in my google drive.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2z7CuKqaQZvemVPS2J6YjEzWkE&usp=sharing

Comment: its right there in the root, just gave you the whole thing should you need anything else.