# Remove Parallax background on brooklyn theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an Index.php file that I need to use as a custom page that I would like to have use some of the themes styles and elements Navigation, Footer, Contact Form, ETC.... The default header seems to be calling the body and its very difficult to find the parts of the header. I have been making a considerable amount of changes so the file in drive should be kept updated until I get this resolved.

Currently I have the page/code working thanks to @David and the advice given in this question:
[run php application within wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189328/run-php-application-within-wordpress)

(links and files removed for privacy, and search engine listings removal)

Comment: ok have you got the code of header.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a few files missing so I cant test this template itself.

But it is simply a case of replacing php code that calls for a variable with actual output (from view source) to create the template you want.

Go back to using the default index.php (remove the header/footer calls). 
Create a new template with the code below and link to it (using the rewrite code from the previous Q you linked above)

There is quite a bit of code in the header.php that calls variables set from the db but hopefully the below code will remove the parallex classes, if not copy the header file and call it header-custom.php. You can replace get_header('custom') to call this header instead. Anywhere you see a php tag inside a html element tag, replace with the actual output you can see in view source.

```
    <?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying 404 pages (Not Found).
     *
     * @package unitedthemes
     */

    get_header(); 

    ?>

        <div class="grid-container">

            <div id="primary" class="grid-parent grid-100 tablet-grid-100 mobile-grid-100">

                <div class="grid-70 prefix-15 mobile-grid-100 tablet-grid-100">

                <header class="page-header fullwidth ut-header-light">
                    <h1 class="page-title"><span><?php _e('RepairStatus'); ?></span></h1>  
                </header>

               <?php require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/repairstatus/index.php'?>

                </div><!-- .page-header --> 

            </div><!-- .grid-100 mobile-grid-100 tablet-grid-100 -->

        </div><!-- .grid-container -->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

header-custom.php contents (call using `get_header('custom');` )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <?php ut_meta_hook(); //action hook, see inc/ut-theme-hooks.php ?>


    <?php if ( defined('WPSEO_VERSION') ) : ?>

        <!-- Title -->
        <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php ut_meta_theme_hook(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- RSS & Pingbacks -->
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <?php if( ot_get_option( 'ut_favicon' ) ) : ?>

        <?php 

        /* get icon info */
        $favicon = ot_get_option( 'ut_favicon' );
        $favicon_info = pathinfo( $favicon ); 
        $type = NULL;

        if( isset($favicon_info['extension']) && $favicon_info['extension'] == 'png' ) {
            $type = 'type="image/png"';
        }

         if( isset($favicon_info['extension']) && $favicon_info['extension'] == 'ico' ) {
            $type = 'type="image/x-icon"';
        }

         if( isset($favicon_info['extension']) && $favicon_info['extension'] == 'gif' ) {
            $type = 'type="image/gif"';
        }

        ?>

        <link rel="shortcut&#x20;icon" href="<?php echo $favicon; ?>" <?php echo $type; ?> />
        <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $favicon; ?>" <?php echo $type; ?> />

    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- Apple Touch Icons -->    
    <?php if( ot_get_option( 'ut_apple_touch_icon_iphone' ) ) :?>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php echo ot_get_option( 'ut_apple_touch_icon_iphone' ); ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( ot_get_option( 'ut_apple_touch_icon_ipad' ) ) : ?>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="<?php echo ot_get_option( 'ut_apple_touch_icon_ipad' ); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( ot_get_option( 'ut_apple_touch_icon_iphone_retina' ) ) : ?>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="<?php echo ot_get_option( 'ut_apple_touch_icon_iphone_retina' ); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( ot_get_option( 'ut_apple_touch_icon_ipad_retina' ) ) :?>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="<?php echo ot_get_option( 'ut_apple_touch_icon_ipad_retina' ); ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]--> 

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<?php 

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Needed Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

$scrollto       = ot_get_option('ut_scrollto_effect');
$scrollto       = !empty( $scrollto['easing'] ) ? $scrollto['easing'] : 'linear' ;
$scrollspeed    = ot_get_option('ut_scrollto_speed'  , '650'); 

$ut_site_border_body_class = ot_get_option( 'ut_site_border', 'hide' ) == 'show' ? 'ut-site-border' : '';
$ut_site_top_header_body_class = ot_get_option( 'ut_top_header', 'hide' ) == 'show' ? 'ut-has-top-header' : '';
$ut_site_border_header_class = ot_get_option( 'ut_site_border', 'hide' ) == 'show' ? 'bordered-navigation' : '';
$ut_top_header_class = ot_get_option( 'ut_top_header' , 'hide' ) == 'show' ? 'bordered-top' : '';

?>

<body id="ut-sitebody" class="error404 " data-scrolleffect="easeInOutExpo" data-scrollspeed="1300">


<a class="ut-offset-anchor" id="top" style="top:0px !important;"></a>

<?php 

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Pre Loader Overlay
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

if( ot_get_option('ut_use_image_loader') == 'on' ) : 

    if( ut_dynamic_conditional('ut_use_image_loader_on') ) : ?>

    <div class="ut-loader-overlay"></div>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>


<?php ut_before_header_hook(); // action hook, see inc/ut-theme-hooks.php ?> 


<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Navigation Setting
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/* skin */
$ut_navigation_skin = ot_get_option('ut_navigation_skin' , 'ut-header-light');

/* visibility */
$headerstate = NULL;

if( is_home() || is_front_page() || is_singular('portfolio') || get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'ut_activate_page_hero' , true ) == 'on' ) {

    if( ot_get_option('ut_navigation_state' , 'off') == 'off' ) {
        $headerstate = 'ha-header-hide';
    }

}

/* width */
$navigation_width = ot_get_option('ut_navigation_width' , 'centered');
$logo_push = ( $navigation_width == 'fullwidth' ) ? 'push-5' : '';
$navigation_pull = ( $navigation_width == 'fullwidth' ) ? 'pull-5' : '';

/* main navigation settings*/
$mainmenu = array('echo'             => false,
                  'container'        => 'nav',
                  'container_id'     => 'navigation',
                  'fallback_cb'      => 'ut_default_menu',
                  'container_class'  => 'grid-80 hide-on-tablet hide-on-mobile ' . $navigation_pull ,
                  'items_wrap'       => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                  'theme_location'   => 'primary', 
                  'walker'           => new ut_menu_walker()
);

/* mobile navigation settings */                         
$mobilemenu = array('echo'              => false,
                    'container'         => 'nav',
                    'container_id'      => 'ut-mobile-nav',
                    'menu_id'           => 'ut-mobile-menu',
                    'menu_class'        => 'ut-mobile-menu',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'ut_default_menu',
                    'container_class'   => 'ut-mobile-menu mobile-grid-100 tablet-grid-100 hide-on-desktop',
                    'items_wrap'        => '<div class="ut-scroll-pane"><ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul></div>',
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary', 
                    'walker'            => new ut_menu_walker()
);














/* check if current page has an option tp show a hero */
//$ut_activate_page_hero = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'ut_activate_page_hero' , true );                      
$ut_activate_page_hero= false // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------not sure what this returns....           

?>

<!-- commented out ----------------------------------------------------->
<?php // get_template_part( 'partials/top', 'header' ); ?> 










<!-- header section -->
<header id="header-section" class="ha-header fullwidth ut-header-light ">

    <?php if( $navigation_width == 'centered' ) :?>

    <div class="grid-container">

    <?php endif; ?> 

        <div class="ha-header-perspective">
            <div class="ha-header-front">

                <div class="grid-20 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-50 <?php echo $logo_push; ?>">

                    <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'ut_site_logo' ) ) : ?>

                        <?php 

                        $sitelogo = !is_front_page() && !is_home() && ( $ut_activate_page_hero == 'off' || empty($ut_activate_page_hero) ) ? get_theme_mod( 'ut_site_logo_alt' ) : get_theme_mod( 'ut_site_logo' );                        

                        $alternate_logo = get_theme_mod( 'ut_site_logo_alt' ) ? get_theme_mod( 'ut_site_logo_alt' ) : get_theme_mod( 'ut_site_logo' ) ;?>

                        <div class="site-logo">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img data-altlogo="<?php echo $alternate_logo; ?>" src="<?php echo $sitelogo; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"></a>
                        </div>

                    <?php else : ?>

                        <div class="site-logo">
                            <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                        </div>

                    <?php endif; ?>                 

                </div>    

                <?php

                /* main and mobile menu cache */
                if( ot_get_option('ut_use_cache' , 'off') == 'on' ) {

                    $language_prefix =  defined('ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE') ? '_' . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE : '';

                    $main_menu      = get_transient('ut_main_menu' . get_the_ID() . $language_prefix );
                    $mobile_menu    = get_transient('ut_mobile_menu' . get_the_ID() . $language_prefix  );
                    $cacheTime      = ot_get_option('ut_cache_ltime' , '10');

                    if ($main_menu === false) {

                        $main_menu = wp_nav_menu( $mainmenu );                        
                        set_transient('ut_main_menu' . get_the_ID() . $language_prefix , $main_menu, 60*$cacheTime);

                    } 

                    if ($mobile_menu === false) {

                        $mobile_menu = wp_nav_menu( $mobilemenu );
                        set_transient('ut_mobile_menu' . get_the_ID() . $language_prefix  , $mobile_menu, 60*$cacheTime);

                    } 


                } else {

                    $main_menu   = wp_nav_menu( $mainmenu );
                    $mobile_menu = wp_nav_menu( $mobilemenu );

                } ?>                

                <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>

                    <?php echo $main_menu; ?>

                    <div class="ut-mm-trigger tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-50 hide-on-desktop">
                        <button class="ut-mm-button"></button>
                    </div>

                    <?php echo $mobile_menu; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
            </div><!-- close .ha-header-perspective -->

    <?php if( $navigation_width == 'centered') :?>        

    </div> 

    <?php endif; ?>

</header><!-- close header -->

<div class="clear"></div>




<!-- Commented this out too --------------------->

<?php// get_template_part( 'template-part', 'hero' ); ?>       








<!-- just in case commented this out-->
<?php // ut_before_content_hook(); // action hook, see inc/ut-theme-hooks.php ?>

<div id="main-content" class="wrap ha-waypoint" data-animate-up="ha-header-hide" data-animate-down="ha-header-small">

    <a class="ut-offset-anchor" id="to-main-content"></a>

        <div class="main-content-background">
```

Comment: That should be every file that is available to me, what files were you looking for?

Comment: Just want to clarify, I should strip all the modifications out of index.php except commenting out headerstatus.php and footerstatus.php.

remove the code we placed in functions.php and completely redo that following the instructions there. then use the template provided below?

when i do so am i placing this code into the index.php file?
or am i making some kind of call to it using the code above as a custom header? with a get header('custom')

Comment: yes revert back to the original index file and strip out the headercall and footer call. All you need to do is change the path on the other code to call your new file instead of index.php directly. the code above will call the index file. if that doesn't remove the parallax effect then we need to look at the header.php

Comment: I understand! make the functions.php code point to the new file we are making now. any suggestions on the name and folder location of this file you wrote above? then we will allow this file to call the header, index.php from repair status and as well as calling in the footer.

is there any reason we cant just call this index.php? place it in the repair status folder there by negating the need to rewrite our functions?
then just naming our original index.php something else? and using this file to call it? such as 
`<?php require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/repairstatus/statuscheck.php'?>`

Comment: I tried this that i mentioned last. renamed the index to statuscheck.php, and the new file index, as to not have to rewrite our functions keeping our naming structure in tact.  
  
It is exactly the same as before, php code works - tested. default theme styles apply to the tables and fonts, blog still visible top & center.

navigation, footer, and contact form all working.

also this is the version live currently if you would like to view it @  
  
accuratepctech.com/repairstatus

Comment: seriously annoying, i have updated what the new header should look like, the parallex effect is contained in a container called hero, so see what this looks like

Comment: I've been looking around pretty hard too. but yea I've seen that it looks like there is one or two types of predefined pages that don't get tagged with that, but every time I try to remove what appears to call it it still shows up!

if you look at template-part-hero.php it seems to define what the hero section contains for each page type.

Comment: Okay so comparing the 2 pages repairstatus, and the version i made from within wordpress's page creation options.    
    
repairstatus line 149: 
  
    `<body id="ut-sitebody" class="page page-id-5686 page-template-default " data-scrolleffect="easeInOutExpo" data-scrollspeed="1300">

<a class="ut-offset-anchor" id="top" style="top:0px !important;"></a>`
   
   
Emsisoft-Renewal Line 145:   
  
    `<body id="ut-sitebody" class="blog " data-scrolleffect="easeInOutExpo" data-scrollspeed="1300"><a class="ut-offset-anchor" id="top" style="top:0px !important;"></a>`
  
Thoughts?

Comment: Also inside the /Partials folder   
  
hero-custom  
hero-dynamic  
hero-image  
hero-slider  
hero-splithero  
hero-tabs  
hero-transition  
hero-video  
  
  
I'm reading through those now, but it would appear that those files contain the rules for the different types of hero functionality, that this theme offers options for. I believe that template-part-hero.php helps to define which pages get which options, and then line 21 of that file loads the partials file that it needs to execute that function. unless im reading it wrong

Comment: yes that would be good, did you upload the header file yet ill have a quick look at it? See the problem for me is, those files were missing from the the folder you uploaded, if i could install the theme, i can just see what db values its pulling etc. But stick with the template i gave you, its just figuring out what classes to put in, i can give you a static file no problem, but then any menu changes wont take effect on this page, but it will get it done for you?

Comment: its in that folder, here's a new link, maybe permissions are wrong.

Comment: if it keeps that up ill zip it all, and re-upload it. so you can have it.

Comment: still cant see it, there was meant to be a subfolder in there i think. just zip it up and ill have a look in the morn.

Comment: I'm zipping it directly off of a fresh backup from the FTP server.

Comment: Custom Header you wrote worked, way to go man, you are the best!

Comment: I made sure to up vote every comment you made on both posts, I cant express how thankful I am for your help. also i made edits and removed any and all posts/comments with links referencing my google account or web domain (google was indexing this and the other post when people searched for my business name), thanks again.

Comment: Well I only have to change the background color of my navigation so my logo appears correct now.

Comment: in the header code you wrote, I need to be able to use $alternate_logo, Instead $sitelogo around line 220. $site logo is half unreadable because the white background.

Comment: just insert the logo url in manually. If you go to chrome and visit the page, right clicking on a element will show you the html and css on the right, you can tinker with the colors there, you might need to select a few elements to find the one you need to change but any css changes you want you can just pop onto your template inside style rules.